# Which are the benefits of adding jar externally android project?

Tags: android, jar, size, apk

I just want to differnece between putting jars in libs folder and adding it externally. Really it does  matters for the size of apk. please share your suggestions.

Comment: What does "adding it externally" mean?

Comment: i mean putting directly in lib folder or add external jar from build configuration

Comment: What does "add external jar from build configuration" mean?